Generating function for A140717

Let $T(n, k)$ be A140717 (i.e., triangle read by rows: $T(n,k)$ is the number of Dyck paths $d$ of semilength $n$ such that sum of peakheights of $d$ - number of peaks of $d$ equals $k$ ($n \geqslant 0, 0 \leqslant k \leqslant \left\lfloor\frac{n^2}{4}\right\rfloor$)). Here ordinary generating functions is $G(t,z) = H(t,\frac{1}{t},z)$ where
$$
H(t,x,z) = 1 + zH(t,x,z)(H(t,tx,z)-1+tx).
$$
There is a Maple program given in OEIS that give a hint how to calculate $H(t,x,z)$:
$$
R(k,t,x,z) = \cfrac{1}{1+z-t^{k+1}xz-zR(k+1,t,x,z)}.
$$
In other words, we have
$$
H(t,x,z) = \cfrac{1}{1+z-txz-\cfrac{z}{1+z-t^2 xz-\cfrac{z}{1+z-t^3 xz-\cfrac{z}{1+z-t^4 xz-\cfrac{z}{\ddots}}}}}.
$$

How obvious is it? Is there a way to prove it? Is there an easier way to calculate $H(t,x,z)$?
